# You ask too much

Tags: meaning

a. You ask too much.

Does that mean

1. You are demanding too much.
2. You are asking for too much money.
3. You ask too many questions.

I think it can definitely mean (1) and (2), which is basically a variant of (1). I am not sure it can mean (3) though. I wouldn't use it instead of (3), but I don't see a reason not to!

Comment: It could mean any of those things, depending on **context**.

Answer (score 4):

Usually it means 1, sometimes 2. Usually in the context of someone proposing some sort of deal.

"I will give you the map if you agree to rescue my brother."

"You ask too much."

In the right context, it COULD mean #3. But that would be unusual. Like,

"Daddy, why is the sky blue? How do birds fly? If dogs could talk, would German Shepherds speak German?"

"Enough! You ask too much."

But that would be unusual, not usually how native speakers would use the phrase.